# iolib with hangup condition not catched when read-line

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am a newer in common lisp, when I use iolib to write server, I found when telnet to the server, then disconnect the telnet, server throw

**unknown type specifier: HANGUP**

when I print backtrace, I found it appeared when read-line in make-server-line-echoer executed. I use handler-case there, but not work. Any help?

this is my code here:

```
(ql:quickload 'iolib)

(defpackage :com.server.test
  (:use :sockets :iomux :common-lisp))
(in-package :com.server.test)

(defvar *server-event-base* nil)

(defun make-server-line-echoer (socket)
  (lambda (fd event exception)
    (handler-case
        (progn
          (let ((line (read-line socket)))
            (format t "Read ~A~%" line)
            (format socket "~A~%" line)
            (finish-output socket)))
      (socket-connection-reset-error ()
        (format t "Connection reset by peer~%")
        (close socket))
      (hangup ()
        (format t "Client close connection on write~%")
        (close socket))
      (end-of-file ()
        (format t "Client closed connection on read~%")
        (close socket)))))

(defun make-server-listener-handler (socket)
  (lambda (fd event exception)
    (let ((client (accept-connection socket :wait t)))
      (when client
        (multiple-value-bind (who port)
            (remote-name client)
          (format t "Accept a client from ~A:~A~%" who port)
          (set-io-handler *server-event-base*
                          (socket-os-fd client)
                          :read
                          (make-server-line-echoer
                           client)))))))

(defun run-server (&key port)
  (setf *server-event-base* (make-instance 'event-base))
  (let ((listener (make-socket :connect :passive
                               :address-family :internet
                               :type :stream
                               :ipv6 nil
                               :external-format '(:utf-8 :eol-style :crlf))))
    (bind-address listener +ipv4-unspecified+ :port port :reuse-addr t)
    (listen-on listener :backlog 5)
    (format t "Listening on socket bound to: ~A:~A~%"
            (local-host listener)
            (local-port listener))
    (set-io-handler *server-event-base*
                    (socket-os-fd listener)
                    :read
                    (make-server-listener-handler listener))
    (handler-case
        (event-dispatch *server-event-base*)
      (socket-connection-reset-error ()
        (format t "Connection reset by peer~%"))
      (hangup ()
        (format t "Client close connection on write~%"))
      (end-of-file ()
        (format t "Client closed connection on read~%")))
    (format t "Close connection now~%")))

(run-server :port 3000)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `use` `iolib.streams`, because the `hangup` condition is defined in that package.